# Function timer PHP

Tags: php

I have to make a function to add Woods in a game for a player.

I wanna make a function to timing, just like the setTimeOut of javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

But i have to do it in server side, because it's a game and in client side it could be hacked

I've tried the function Sleep, but it made the page load forever

Yes, it have to be a infinite loop, because it always add more wood

Code:

```
function Criar_Madeira($a) {
        $a->madeira += 500;
        sleep(10);
        Criar_Madeira($a);
}

Criar_Madeira($a[1]);
```

Comment: `sleep()` should not make the page "load forever" it will do noting for the 10 seconds you told it to

Comment: I think use cron with 1s can be better choice

Comment: every ten seconds? do you need it real time? why not just do calculations based on time. just have a start time and end time and make your wood increments from there

Comment: if you're just gonna execute a function every n time then cron is the fit for you.

Comment: You need to remember the web is stateless for the most part. You'll need to save a timestamp (perhaps in a user session, perhaps in a db field) and each time the page loads add the appropriate amount of wood.